# Compositing text over an image on upload with Paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

My app has a form which allows the uploading of an image and the entering of a caption.

I want to dynamically composite the submitted caption text onto the image.

Currently I can upload the image and process it with a custom Paperclip process. This will composite pre-defined text onto the image as follows :

```
class Caption < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :captioned_photo,
              processors: [:captioner],
              styles: {
                captioned_photo: {
                  format: '.png',
                  caption_text: 'text to overlay on image'
                }
              } 

    belongs_to :submission
end
```

How can I pass the user submitted text into the processor? Something like :

```
class Caption < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :captioned_photo,
              processors: [:captioner],
              styles: {
                captioned_photo: {
                  format: '.png',
                  caption_text: user_uploaded_text
                }
              } 

    belongs_to :submission
end
```

Thanks.

UPDATE :

lamas are indeed the way to go :

```
has_attached_file :captioned_photo,
              processors: [:captionbitch],
              styles: -> (attachment) {
                  {
                  polarized: {
                    format: '.png',
                    is_polarized: true,
                    the_text: attachment.instance.text
                  }
                }
              }
```

This allows dynamic assignment of properties within the `has_attached_file` method call. `attachment.instance.text` returns the data field named text.

Comment: What processor are you using? Think open sourcing its code?

Comment: @KazimZaidi [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is the processor and it's already open source.

Comment: I meant the `captionbitch` processer, as seen in the code above. I searched for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: @dwkns yea curious to know what your `captionbitch` processor looks like, I'm trying to do something similar right now!

Comment: It's here : https://github.com/dwkns/captioner/blob/master/lib/paperclip_processors/captionbitch.rb It was a long time ago and I can't remember how it works now sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet a lambda will help you here. Go to the thought bot/paperclip github pages and search for "Dynamic Styles".

Comment: Thanks David, this pointed me in the right direction. Turns out to be spectacularly easy to get any instance data you need in this respect. See above.